(Splunk SDK) How do I retrieve a stored REST API key during the validation stage?
I'm writing a modular script.
I have an API key stored by splunk encrypted. During the validation stage I can't use the SDK to call splunk to retrieve the key because the SDK will not create a connection to Splunk during this stage.
When the SDK is streaming events it automatically connects to splunk, but I can't figure out how it does this, and I can't figure out how it does it without authentication details.
Any way I can have my python script connect to splunk without hardcoding some authentication details?
to be able to connect my script to splunk before streaming events in to splunk using the splunk python SDK
